# Parse http request header

Tags: java

I am getting a request header with value containing multiple double quotes, How do i parse it in my java code ?

here is how header looks like

pp-groups: "Administrator","SuperUser","view","Edit"

Comment: The question is related to basic Java rather than any web related stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string either with `split()` or `StringTokenizer` and then trim the quotes off.

```
String header=request.getHeader("pp-groups");
for (String val : header.replace("\"", "").split(",")) System.out.println(val);
```

Doesnt support inline-quotes though, not sure if this is required

Comment: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead." So, don't suggest string tokenizer.

Comment: split - the recommended method - "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: @brunoais haha, at about the same time :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not split and trim?

```
public static void main(String...arg) {
  List<String> vals = new ArrayList<String>();
  String header = "\"Administrator\",\"\"Super\" User\",,\"\",view,\"Edit\"";
  for(String val : header.split(",")) {
    if(val.length() > 0) {
      if(val.charAt(0) == '\"' && val.charAt(val.length()-1) == '\"') {
        if(val.length() > 2) { //not just a pair of quotes
          vals.add(val.substring(1, val.length()-1));
        }
      } else {
        vals.add(val);
      }
    }
  }
  System.out.println(vals);
}
```

Outputs:

```
[Administrator, "Super" User, view, Edit]
```

Comment: You could add error checking by looking at `.chartAt(0)` and `.chartAt(val.length())`

Comment: There, updated to deal with values that are not quotes mixed with values that are

Comment: And values that contain quotes inside

Comment: @AlexanderM, empty and quoted empty :)

Comment: @sanjay, the backslashes come from defining a String in Java that contains quotes.  If you wrapped this code into a function that took as its argument the header value and gave as it's output a list of unquoted values then I think you would have what you need.

Comment: In this code, val.charAt(0) returns a '"' not '\"'. Are you sure this works?

Comment: That is an escaped quotation mark, but maybe in a character literal its not nessescary to escape them. Habit I guess.

Comment: I tested it, meanwhile. Both work, but using '\"' does not make sense to me :) and java compiler probably just gets it and moves on.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the `split` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: That won't be enough for quoted strings.

Comment: it will, actually, you just need to be clever about how you're handling it. Regular Expression matching is definitely the way to go here though.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're trying to do this manually, as opposed to using existing framework for HTTP requests, you will need to parse the string yourself. The best way to do this is to make use of Regular Expressions (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ ... the important part of this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html). Alternatively, you can spend some time messing around with various String methods such as .split and .substring